# Smart Pointer Destructor Race Condition

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, race-condition

Given the destructor below:

```
~shared_ptr(){
    *_ref_count--;
    if(*_ref_count==0){
        delete _p;
        delete _ref_count;
    }
}
```

If

> _ref_count == 2

can two threads releasing the smart pointer cause to double deleting (crash) and/or no deleting at all (memory leak) and how?

Comment: is this your code or an extract from a c++ standard library?

Comment: What's the type of `_ref_count`? Is it `atomic`?

Comment: @pm100 no. Its just a naive implementation.

Comment: Even if `_ref_count` is atomic, double delete can still happen.

Comment: yes - there is a race if you plan to use this in a multi threaded environment.

Comment: @Jesper juhl no. It's integer.

Comment: If it were `if(--ref_count == 0)` with `std::atomic<int> ref_count` would double delete still be possible?

Comment: @patatahooligan: No

Comment: @tkausl please can you explain how?

Comment: @patatahooligan: Yes, but if you use `atomic_fetch_sub(_ref_count, 1) == 0` it would be thread-safe (or `(*_ref_count -= 1) == 0` which is equivalent if `ref_count` is `std::atomic`)

Comment: Are there any thread safety guarantees made by the library you are using? A common design decision is to make shared_ptr "as threadsafe as raw pointers". Which means that the DTor (arguably) does not have to be threadsafe.

Comment: If you are on a windows platform you can use InterlockedDecrement to decrement and get the value in one atomic operation.

Comment: As many other people already said the decrement and test for 0 are not atomic which makes it vulnerable. Thread 1 can decrement the ref count, interrupted preemptively and when rescheduled the ref count may be zero due to the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer

Yes there is a race condition. Two thread can decrement and test at the same time.

Investigate std::atomic or wrap in a mutex or use std::shared_ptr (the best answer)

Comment: This is just a theoretical question.

Comment: this is just a theoretical answer